# Delete gmails based on specific criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, automation, gmail, del, recycle-bin

I am researching a google apps script to delete an e-mail based on time.
I have set up a daily agenda but they fill my inbox after some time.

[daily agenda e-mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlNT.png)

I was thinking of deleting those e-mails automatically every next day, since I get updates every day after 5 AM perhaps setting a script to delete them the next day before 5AM should work but I haven't found a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Deletes all emails that are not on my whitelist

```
function deleteAllEmailsNotWhiteListed() {
  const acct = getGlobal('abrevEmail');
  var idA = [];
  GmailApp.getTrashThreads().forEach(t => { Gmail.Users.Threads.remove("me", t.getId()) });
  for (let k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
    switch (k) {
      case 0:
        var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
        break;
      case 1:
        var threads = GmailApp.getSpamThreads();
        break;
    }
    if (threads) {
      for (let i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        const messages = threads[i].getMessages();
        if (messages) {
          for (let j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
            let msg = messages[j];
            let id = msg.getId();
            let sub = msg.getSubject().replace(/[^\s\w"!,?']/g, '');
            let from = msg.getFrom();
            let to = msg.getTo();
            let body = msg.getBody();
            let m = { id: id, from: from, to: to, subject: sub, account: acct }
            if (!isWhiteListed(m)) {
              idA.push(id);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (idA.length > 0) {
    var request = { "ids": idA };
    Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete(request, "me");
  }
}

function isWhiteListed(msg) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(getGlobal('ssid'));
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(getGlobal('wlid'));
  const wlog = ss.getSheetByName(getGlobal('wlog'));
  const sr = 2;
  const rg = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 1);
  const wl = rg.getDisplayValues().flat().map(e => e.toLowerCase());
  if (wl.length == 0) throw ('Error: WhiteList has no content');
  let obj = decomposeEmailsWithTitle({ raw: msg.from, email: '', title: '' });
  let status = wl.indexOf(obj.email.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  wlog.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"), obj.email, msg.to, msg.subject, status, msg.account]);
  return status;
}
```

#### Here's a version that only concerns itself with the deleting emails that are older than The current date

```
function deleteAllEmailsNotWhiteListed() {
  const dt = new Date();
  const ydtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate()-1).valueOf();
  const acct = getGlobal('abrevEmail');
  var idA = [];
  GmailApp.getTrashThreads().forEach(t => { Gmail.Users.Threads.remove("me", t.getId()) });
  for (let k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
    switch (k) {
      case 0:
        var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
        break;
      case 1:
        var threads = GmailApp.getSpamThreads();
        break;
    }
    if (threads) {
      for (let i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        const messages = threads[i].getMessages();
        if (messages) {
          for (let j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
            let msg = messages[j];
            let id = msg.getId();
            let d = msg.getDate();
            let dtv = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf()
            if (dtv <= ydtv) {//modifed
              idA.push(id);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (idA.length > 0) {
    var request = { "ids": idA };
    Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete(request, "me");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your extremely fast answer. Can you please explain to me how the script works and if I need to make any changes to the script? I am still learning how to code and I would enjoy understanding how it works.

Comment: Well I'd recommend getting a javascript reference and begin going through it.  Ask questions as you come to them.

Comment: I tried to set up the script but isn't working as intended, it deleted every mail instead of leaving today's agenda.

Comment: I can assure you that I use this function to manage my own email. You may have to adjust the criteria to fit your own needs

Comment: Ok, I might be doing something very wrong. I will fix it. Thank you Cooper.

Comment: I updated the code to concern itself with making it's determination to delete solely on the basis of date.  Any date equal to and less than yesterdays date will be deleted